# How does computeIfAbsent fail ConcurrentHashMap randomly?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have the following code, it is a toy code but makes possible to reproduce the problem:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class TestClass3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Setup data that we will be playing with concurrently
        List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j");

        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> keyValueMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String key : keys) {
            int[] randomInts = new Random().ints(10000, 0, 10000).toArray();
            keyValueMap.put(key, stream(randomInts).boxed().collect(toList()));
        }

        // Entering danger zone, concurrently transforming our data to another shape
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        Map<Integer, Set<String>> valueKeyMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        for (String key : keys) {
            es.submit(() -> {
                for (Integer value : keyValueMap.get(key)) {
                    valueKeyMap.computeIfAbsent(value, val -> new HashSet<>()).add(key);
                }
            });
        }
        // Wait for all tasks in executorservice to finish
        es.shutdown();
        es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        // Danger zone ends..

        // We should be in a single-thread environment now and safe
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer integer : valueKeyMap.keySet()) {
            String collect = valueKeyMap
                    .get(integer)
                    .stream()
                    .sorted()  // This will blow randomly
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
            stringBuilder.append(collect);  // just to print something..
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.length());
    }
}
```

When I run this code over and over again, it will usually run without any exceptions and will print some number.. However from time time (1 out of 10 tries approximately) I will get an exception akin to:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.accept(SortedOps.java:369)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1556)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
    at biz.tugay.TestClass3.main(TestClass3.java:40)
```

I am pretty certain it has something to do with

```
valueKeyMap.computeIfAbsent(value, val -> new HashSet<>()).add(key);
```

If I change this part as follows, I never get an exception:

```
synchronized (valueKeyMap) {
    valueKeyMap.computeIfAbsent(value, val -> new HashSet<>()).add(key);
}
```

I am *thinking* `computeIfAbsent` is still modifying the `valueKeyMap` even after all threads are finished.

Could someone explain how come this code is failing randomly, what the reason is? Or is there a totally different reason I am unable to see perhaps and I am wrong in my assumption that `computeIfAbsent` is to blame?

Comment: `HashSet` isn't thread safe.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I do not understand, I am not accessing `HashSet` from multiple threads when `sorting` it? The exception happens when I am back to single-threaded operation, isn't it?

Comment: You're accessing it from multiple threads when you're adding to it. The "bad state" is only revealed later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn't in the `computeIfAbsent` call, but rather in the `.add(key)` at the end: you can have multiple threads trying to add elements to the same HashSet, with nothing to ensure safe concurrent access. Since HashSet isn't threadsafe, this doesn't work properly, and the HashSet sometimes ends up in a corrupt state. Later, when you try to iterate over the HashSet to get a string, it blows up due to this corrupt state. (Judging from your exception, the HashSet thinks its backing array is longer than it actually is, so it's trying to access out-of-bounds array elements.)

Even in the runs where you *don't* get an exception, you probably sometimes end up "dropping" elements that should have gotten added, but where concurrent updates mean that some updates were lost.

Comment: Is the solution simply to use a concurrent `Set` implementation such as [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) instead of that `HashSet`?

Comment: @BasilBourque I do not think the post becomes any better when it yells `hashset::add is not thread-safe`.

Comment: @KorayTugay A heading is not yelling. A heading is a feature built into Stack Overflow. A heading is a summary, distinguishing one answer from another. A heading guides the reader as their eye scans up and down the page of multiple answers.

Comment: @BasilBourque: There are quite a few ways the OP can fix this: using a threadsafe set implementation (either a concurrent one or a synchronized one), or `synchronize`-ing on the HashSet, or using the `compute` solution that Andy Turner suggests in an answer below. Since the question is only about what the problem is, and the OP seems sufficiently comfortable with multithreading that (s)he could solve the problem on his/her own once it was explained, I decided not to go into it.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you, seems like I misinterpreted it. Sometimes people use large fonts for yelling, like RTFM or UNIX != LINUX and so on.. I thought it was the case here too. I was wrong it seems.

Answer (score 4):

`ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` executes atomically, that is, only one thread can access the value associated with a given key at a time.

However, there is no such guarantee once the value is returned. The `HashSet` can be accessed by multiple writing threads, and as such is not being accessed thread-safely.

Instead, you can do something like this:

```
valueKeyMap.compute(value, (k, v) -> {
    if (v == null) {
      v = new HashSet<>();
    }
    v.add(key);
    return v;
});
```

which works because `compute` is atomic too.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that when using `synchronized` you do not get an exception should already shed some light as to where the problem is. As already stated the problem is indeed the `HashSet` as it is not thread safe. This is also stated in the documentation of the collection.

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access a hash set concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the set, it *must* be synchronized externally. This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the set.

The solution is to either use the `synchronized` block or make use of a thread safe `CollectionView` such as `KeySetView` which you can get using `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`.